# How to delete related rows in a many to many relationship (SQL Server 2008 + Entity Framework 4)

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

For example, let's say that I have this 3 tables :

```
Table Customers:
CustomerID

Table Addresses:
AddressId

Table Customers_Addresses
CustomerID
AddressID
```

On SQL Server Management Studio, for the two FK I put "Delete Rule" and "Update Rule" to "Cascade".

So, when i delete a customer, all rows in "Customers_Addresses" that reference the CustomerID are deleted.
Now, if I want that SQL Server 2008 also delete all rows in the "Addresses" table that are related to the customer i just deleted, what can i do ?

I read that i can load all related "Addresses" in my Customer object and call "DeleteObject" for all instances of Addresses. I'm not satisfied of this solution, i prefer a solution on SQL Server 2008, if it exists.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `on delete trigger` in `table Customers_Addresses` that will `delete` the info from `table Addresses`.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SQLServer/0440__Trigger/CREATETRIGGERFORDELETE.htm) is a full example!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! this the trigger i use : USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[CustomersHasAddresses]    Script Date: 12/21/2011 15:11:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:  <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CustomersHasAddresses] 
   ON  [dbo].[Customers_Addresses]
   FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
 
    DELETE Addresses WHERE AddressID IN (SELECT AddressID FROM deleted)

END